# Single-line input to multiline output in Unix

Tags: unix

How can I use a filter to display something like:

echo "Hello there" |

```
H
e
l
l
o

t
h
e
r
e
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a couple:

1. `fold`

   ```
   echo "Hello there" | fold -w 1
   H
   e
   l
   l
   o

   t
   h
   e
   r
   e
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   echo "Hello there" | perl -pe 's/(.)/$1\n/g;'
   H
   e
   l
   l
   o

   t
   h
   e
   r
   e
   ```

Comment: The post was edited, I meant to make it display one letter in one line?

Comment: @Znau thanks, unfortunately it was not what the OP wanted :). There was a formatting issue with their question. Fixed now,

Comment: @JurgenMalinao, yes I edited it. If I correctly understood what you meant, the updated answer should do it.

Comment: @terdon indeed, it was edited. still, i keep my comment :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sed` to do this. It's a little more lightweight than perl but still allows you to use regular expressions to express your heart's desires.

```
$ echo "Hello world" | sed -r 's/./&\n/g'
H
e
l
l
o

w
o
r
l
d
```

Comment: Ah, I was just about to write the sed one :). `fold` will be the fastest though since it has no regex to deal with.

Comment: @terdon And you earned an upvote from me. Took a minute to hunt down the `&` backreference; I don't use sed for this kind of things very often. (I doubt something like this would be performance critical in *any* case, however.)

Answer (score 4):

This also works:

```
echo "Hello there" | grep -o .
```

- `.` matches a single character.
- `-o` only prints the match (rather than the whole line).